# Change visibility of Node when User scrolls to it with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I have something like this:

```
<br><br><br>...Lots of BRs...<br><br><br>
<div id="thetarget"></div><div id="show"></div>
<br><br><br>...Lots of BRs...<br><br><br>
```

I want to show the `#show` when user scroll to the `#thetarget` OR/and to manipulate with css styles of the `#thetarget` when user scroll to it, but without "click interaction" of the user as it normally would with `<a href="#thetarget">the target</a>`

Is this even possible with only css code?

If it's not, how can I make this with javascript(not jquery) so it won't be impact on performance at all(=tiny affect)?

Thank you

Comment: keziah, any example, please?

Comment: it is possible see my answer

Comment: Please put a more descriptive title so that others may find the question useful in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do this with pure JS

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  var show = document.getElementById('show');
  
  if (this.pageYOffset > 100) {
    show.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    show.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
#thetarget {
  height: 1000px;
}
#show {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="thetarget">
  <h1>Keep scrolling</h1>
</div>
<div id="show">
  <h1>Revealed</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. The jquery link is unnecessary, in case if someone will want to use this with best performance.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally put the jquery link above but it's now removed.